# Buttons showed when a marker is clicked in a MapsActivity in Android

Tags: java, android, maps

I'm developing a simple app that uses one MapsActivity. Since I'm new to Android app developing, I have some doubts.

I've seen that when you click to a marker you've previously added, two buttons show up on the inferior right corner. One is to open Google Maps itself, and the other to open Google Maps with a route to the marker.

What are the activities that those two buttons start? I would just like to remove those two default buttons and make one myself with a text like "Show route", the problem is that I don't know how to acces to those two buttons (so I can remove them) and the activities they manage.

Thanks.

Comment: Some code please,or what tutorial have you followed?

Comment: My app doesn't do anything more than starting a MapsActivity, adding one marker to the map like: `MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(savedLocation).title("Here I am")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker));

        mMap.addMarker(marker);` Then, by default, when I click the marker on the map I see two buttons on the inferior right corner. I would just like to know how to manage those two buttons and the activities they start.

Comment: and if you tap  on the marker ..two buttons are visibles, is that correct? so onMarkerClick() method has to be  implemented. Can you find out your onMarkerClick(Marker marker) method ?

Comment: I'm not overriding the onMarkerClick() method in my MapsActivity. What I see when I tap on the marker it's just being done by default.

Comment: ok,got it , Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Edit:

Please note that your mMap variable has to be initialized, otherwise you will get a null pointer exception

Comment: Well this would eventually disable those two buttons. Anyway what I'm trying to do, more than just hidding those two buttons, is to implement them manually. You know what I mean? Add two buttons myself and there on their respective listeners do what the default buttons do. So I just need to know what do those two default buttons do when you click them.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. Well I guess that the code you want to re-implement  is compiled under google play services... unfortunately  It is closed source . Good luck

Comment: Yes, I was actually expecting that... Thanks anyway for your help!